# data.table challenge: defining a strata variable for recurrent events

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create a variable called strata for recurrent events. The idea is to define a variable that counts events, but filling previous records. What defines the counting is the variable event as is shown below:

```
id event   cov    strata      year
1   0       0        1        12
1   0       1        1        13
1   1       1        1        14
1   0       1        2        15
1   1       0        2        16
1   1       1        3        17
1   0       0        4        18
1   0       1        4        19
1   0       1        4        20
```

I have tried something like this at least for the event records:

```
id  <- c(rep(1,9), rep(2,5), rep(3,7))
event  <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
cov  <- c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
year  <- c(seq(12,20,1), seq(12,16,1), seq(12,18,1)) 
dat  <- data.table(id,event, cov, year)

dat[,strata:=seq(.N),by="id"]
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: By your description should strata be `1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4` not the example you posted, or am I misunderstanding.

Comment: Some sort of shifted `cumsum` solution should work, (assuming you wnat the strata number to be incremented after an event) but first we need more attention to what the correct output might be.

Comment: the `zoo` package has a function `na.locf` that you could use to fill in the rest of the `NA`s generated with your `seq(.N)` method.

Comment: You are right mnel, strata should be 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an updated solution.

```
dat  <- data.table(id,event, cov, year)
dat[, strata := c(1L,head(cumsum(event)+1L,-1L)), by = id]
```

Comment: The {} could be on the RHS of := in a single call, iiuc?

Comment: I got this error: dat[, strata := {x <-  c(.I[event==1],.N); xd <- c(x[1], diff(x)) rep.int(seq_along(xd), xd)}, by="id"]
Error in rep.int(seq_along(xd), xd) : invalid 'times' value

Comment: Ah. Your example data set did not have more than one `ID`. It looks as if there is an issue where perhaps there are ID values with no events. Post a better example data set and I can work around this.

Comment: I just posted a better example dataset where I got this error: Error in rep.int(seq_along(xd), xd) : invalid 'times' value. Thanks.